Deriving Quaternion Angular Velocity
This page says that Quaternion Angular Velocity is given by
$$\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt} = \vec{w} \bigotimes \vec{s}.$$
Where this is interpreted as Quaternion multiplication.
He derives this by arguing angular velocity is orthogonal to position and therefore the scalar part of the quaternion is zero, therefore the above is the same as
$$\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt} = \vec{w} \times \vec{s}.$$
This argument from my understanding is not correct, since position vector and angular velocity may not be orthogonal.
So how do you correctly derive this?

Write $\vec{w},\vec{s}$ as pure quaternions:\begin{align}
\mathbf{w}&=w_1\mathbf{i}+w_2\mathbf{j}+w_3\mathbf{k},,&
\mathbf{s}&=s_1\mathbf{i}+s_2\mathbf{j}+s_3\mathbf{k},.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{w}\otimes\mathbf{s}=(w_2s_3-w_3s_2)\mathbf{i}+(w_3s_1-w_1s_3)\mathbf{j}+(w_1s_2-w_2s_1)\mathbf{k},.
\end{align}

@KurtG. If you’re doing quaternion multiplication, what happened to the   $\mathbf{i}^2$, etc. terms?

Oops !  There is a term missing: \begin{align} \mathbf{w}\otimes\mathbf{s}=-w_1s_1-w_2s_2-w_3s_3+(w_2s_3-w_3s_2)\mathbf{i}+(w_3s_1-w_1s_3)\mathbf{j}+(w_1s_2-w_2s_1)\mathbf{k},. \end{align} This is not a pure quaternion. But its imaginary part is the cross product of $\vec w$ and $\vec s,.$

Quaternions represent pure rotations and so the general case of screw motion is not accounted for in quaternion algebra.

This is why you should read books and/or peer reviewed journal articles instead of a rndom website written by someone who has just learned how to use quaternions to represent $\text{SO}(3)$.

Ok but regardless where is the proof for what we want to prove?

There is no proof for something that is incorrect (as you noted in OP already). It looks like the author of that page confuses orbital angular velocity with spin angular velocity. The former is uniquely defined by $\vec s$ and $\dot{\vec s}$ and is orthogonal to both. But in the equation $\dot{\vec s}=\vec w\times\vec s$ we have spin angular velocity which is not always orthogonal to $\vec s,.$ See this answer for details.

Sorry, I should have clarified - my question is how we deprive the quaternion kinematic equation for a rotating object

If you want to send this comment to my inbox you should start it with @KurtG . Do you mean "how we derive the quaternion kinematic equation for a rotating object" ? I don't know. As I said: $\dot{\mathbf s}=\mathbf{w\otimes s}$ is not a kinematic equation for a rotating object.
